# difference between jersey Rest apis and org.restlet apis

Tags: java, rest, jersey, restlet

I am new to rest apis in java.I found ,there are mainly two methods to create Rest Apis in java.One method is using Jersey and other i think is using org.restlet (not sure i mean without jersey).so whats the main difference between these two.

Comment: i searched it on google too but couldnt find any proper reason .

Comment: AFAIK - Both provides implementations of JAX-RS and It's upto the user to decide. Restlet provides better extensions like Velocity template engine, freemarker, etc. and Its support for Java SE/EE, OSGi, Android, GAE and GWT with dedicated editions is unique. It also Provides PaaS. Jersey on the other hand provides most of the basic integration JAXB, Spring, etc. but when I had to use velocityEngine I couldn't integrate it with jersey. However I still use Jersey for developing my Rest apis because I've got used to it. If you don't use most of the Restlet features then go with Jersey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restlet provides an API to build and consume RESTful applications. It provides a wide support of HTTP headers and mechanisms described in REST. It also comes with a set of pluggable features like:

- Content negotiation - support of the `Accept*` header
- Routing - provide a flexible way to build the processing chain (filter, authenticator, server resource)
- Authentication - a frame to plug existing scheme for security at the level of the `Authorization` header
- Converter - a frame to integrate entities to serialize / deserialize structured content like JSON, XML, YAML
- Connector - a frame to register and use tools (like Jetty) for serving and calling RESTful applications

Jersey is an implementation of the [JAXRS](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/) specification. You can notice that Restlet also provides an implementation of this specification through its JAXRS extension: https://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/guide/2.3/extensions/jaxrs.